# Is "all" a pronoun or an intensifier?

Tags: word-meaning

> [Hogwarts students were]pulling into platform nine and three-quarters
>   at King’s Cross Station.  It took quite a while for them all to get
>   off the platform. A wizened old guard was up by the ticket barrier,
>   letting them go through the gate in twos and threes so they didn’t
>   attract attention by ***all*** bursting out of a solid wall at once
>   and alarming the Muggles. (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is *all* a pronoun, indicating the students, or an intensifier for bursting out and alarming?

Comment: In my opinion, it refers to the students, who would attract attention by doing a certain action all at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* here acts as a pronoun, the subject of both *bursting* and *alarming*. Its referent is *them* earlier in the sentence, which in turn refers to the students.

Traditional grammar would identify *bursting* and *alarming* as gerunds rather than participles, the nominal objects of the preposition *by*. Contemporary grammars prefer to find the object of *by* in the full non-finite clause *all bursting out of a solid wall at once and alarming the Muggles*. But regardless of what you call *bursting* and *alarming*, they have the ordinary properties of verbs and take their ordinary arguments, both complements and subject.

Note that the same syntactic structure would be in play if JKR had written

> *attract attention by **all of them** bursting out of a solid wall at once*
>   *attract attention by **them** bursting out of a solid wall at once*
>   *attract attention by **their** bursting out of a solid wall at once*
>   *attract attention by **most** bursting out of a solid wall at once*
>   *attract attention by **∅** bursting out of a solid wall at once*

In all of these the emphasized element performs the same syntactic role: subject of the non-finite verb.

Answer (score 2):

*Bursting* is a participle, it doesn't take a subject. There is no function that *all* as a pronoun could serve in this sentence, it has to be an adverb.

*All* isn't an intensifier: it means *all the students*. You can't just remove it: it goes together with *at once*. “(…) so they didn't attract attention by bursting out of a solid wall” would mean that if even a single student burst out of a solid wall, that would alarm the Muggles. With “all (…) at once” added, the sentence means that it's ok if a student bursts out of a solid wall once in a while, but not if all the students do it at the same time (or even if many do it at the same time, there's some hyperbole).

Comment: Not so. As you say, *all* 'means' -that is, stands for- *all the students*. That makes it a pronoun. And *bursting* is a gerund, not a participle.

Comment: @StoneyB Ok with gerund and not participle, but how can *all* be parsed as a subject of *bursting*? You can't say “*they bursting” (whereas you could say “their bursting”). Is “all bursting at once” a different grammatical construction from “bursting all at once”?

Comment: Them's just the rules! (See [this](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), by ELU guru John Lawler, for a marvellously concise treatment.) *All at once* is ambiguous: it may mean either *all at the same time* or *suddenly*, which may be why JKR avoids it. Note that she also carefully avoids the ordinary **by** *twos and threes* to prevent collision with the **by** in this clause.

Comment: As an aside: some linguists no longer distinguish gerund and participle, at least when analyzing Modern English.  In the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, both are described as *gerund-participles*.